# Inserting login OTP into the `OTP` column of my db for the requested email through API

Tags: php, laravel, crud, laravel-8, rest

My API results OTP but it's not getting inserted to the db. I am trying to generate an OTP if the email given as input is a valid one that already exists in db & save it to the `OTP` column in `users` table. It's more like a Login OTP API ,where the otp is just being inserted to db but not sending to a mobile number or email id. Do any one have some guess where am i wrong? I am just a beginner for REST APIs. So, need helps to solve this problem.

```
public function sendotp(Request $request){
            
            $validator = Validator::make
            ($request->all(),
                [
                    'email'    => 'required|email',
                ]
            );
    
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return response()->json(
                    [$validator->errors()],
                    422
                );
            }
            
            
            $email_user = User::where('email',$request->email)->first();
            if($email_user){
    
                $otp = rand(1000,9999);
                
    
                $user = User::where('email','=',$request->email)->update(['OTP' => $otp]);
                $user->save();
               return response()->json($otp);
            }
            else{
    
                return response()->json(['message'=>'No users exists with this email'], 404);
            }
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning response before updating So change like below

```
$user = User::where('email',$request->email)->first();
   if($user){
    
       $otp = rand(1000,9999);
       $user->OTP=$otp;
       $user->save();
       return response()->json($otp);
    
               
    } else{

      return response()->json(['message'=>'No users exists with this email'], 404);
   }
```

Also make sure if you are updating then make column `OTP` fillable in  `User` Model

Comment: See the updated code.i have changed like u said.Now,it shows a postman error "Call to a member function save() on int"

Comment: yes it will not work .use what i have mentioned .completely replace that code with  my answer.

Comment: still doubt then let me know so i can help you to fix

Comment: remove your code  $email_user = User::where('email',$request->email)->first();
            if($email_user){
    
                $otp = rand(1000,9999);
                
    
                $user = User::where('email','=',$request->email)->update(['OTP' => $otp]);
                $user->save();
               return response()->json($otp);
            }
            else{
    
                return response()->json(['message'=>'No users exists with this email'], 404);
            }  and replace with my answered one

Comment: Actually changing my lines & pasting ur code solved that error.Thanks.